# iframe inside div height fixed

Tags: css, html, iframe

I have a div with `height: 485px` and I want to put an iframe inside with a width of 100% so the user can scroll the div and not the scrollbar (Im doing this because I'm using a CSS scrollbar).

```html
<div id="demo1"  style="height:485px; overflow:scroll;float: left;overflow-x: hidden;">
    <iframe height="100%" width="455px"  scrolling="no" frameborder="0" src="www" ></iframe>
</div>
```

I tried to include style to the iframe like `style="height: auto;"` or 100% but doesn't work.

Any suggestion how to check the height of the iframe?
Thanks

Comment: So you're trying to make the IFRAME the full height of the page inside the IFRAME? The answer just posted has information about the best ways to do that, but it's not going to be just a CSS solution (if I understand your question correctly).

Answer (score 0):

To get the height on an iframe, you'll need to communicate between two window. If you only support IE8+, then that's rather simple with [`postmessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/DOM/window.postMessage). You basically use a script inside the iframe (1- the iframe content is owned by you and you add the script, or the owner of the iframe trust you and add your code snippet).

If you want to support older browser, then you'll have a lot of fun [`breaking the cross domain barrier`](http://alexsexton.com/blog/2011/06/breaking-the-cross-domain-barrier-screencast/).

But, that's really the only way you can get the inner height of an iframe.

I'm not sure I've quite understand your use case here, but what it seemed like to me, is that you're loading a complete website in an iframe in order to use some special scrolling effect? If that's really the case, seriously look at other solution, messing around with cross domain communication to get a simple visual effect isn't the best use of time (plus the performance hit of nesting a complete website iframe).

Hope this help!